# How does ggplot2 evaluate factor levels?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Consider this example dataframe:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(item = c("Banana", "Ananas", "Apple", "Blueberry", "Orange",
                      "Spinach", "Cabbage", "Broccoli", "Carrot", "Eggplant"),
             category = c(rep("Fruit", 5), rep("Vegetable", 5)),
             n = c(57, 19, 14, 11, 8, 318, 70, 33, 31, 23))
```

First, I attribute factor levels to `item` by `n`. I also add a variable `item_fct` in order to display the factor levels of `item` in the output table for a better understanding of my problem:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(item = fct_reorder(item, n),
         item_fct = as.numeric(item))
```

```
# A tibble: 10 x 4
   item      category      n item_fct
   <fct>     <chr>     <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 Banana    Fruit        57        8
 2 Ananas    Fruit        19        4
 3 Apple     Fruit        14        3
 4 Blueberry Fruit        11        2
 5 Orange    Fruit         8        1
 6 Spinach   Vegetable   318       10
 7 Cabbage   Vegetable    70        9
 8 Broccoli  Vegetable    33        7
 9 Carrot    Vegetable    31        6
10 Eggplant  Vegetable    23        5
```

This output table and the factor levels make sense to me: `Item` is labeled from 1-10 by `n` in an ascending order.

But if I group it by `category`, I get the following output:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(category) %>% 
  mutate(item = fct_reorder(item, n),
         item_fct = as.numeric(item))
```

```
# A tibble: 10 x 4
# Groups:   category [2]
   item      category      n item_fct
   <fct>     <chr>     <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 Banana    Fruit        57        5
 2 Ananas    Fruit        19        4
 3 Apple     Fruit        14        3
 4 Blueberry Fruit        11        2
 5 Orange    Fruit         8        1
 6 Spinach   Vegetable   318        5
 7 Cabbage   Vegetable    70        4
 8 Broccoli  Vegetable    33        3
 9 Carrot    Vegetable    31        2
10 Eggplant  Vegetable    23        1
```

Here, the factor levels are rather confusing to me. The items, depending on the group, share the same factor levels (1-5). I would still have expected levels from 1-10, but ordered by `n` depending on the respective group. Like this:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 4
   item      category      n item_fct
   <chr>     <chr>     <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 Banana    Fruit        57        5
 2 Ananas    Fruit        19        4
 3 Apple     Fruit        14        3
 4 Blueberry Fruit        11        2
 5 Orange    Fruit         8        1
 6 Spinach   Vegetable   318       10
 7 Cabbage   Vegetable    70        9
 8 Broccoli  Vegetable    33        8
 9 Carrot    Vegetable    31        7
10 Eggplant  Vegetable    23        6
```

**My Question:**

Ultimately, it's hard for me to understand why ggplot2 produces the following plot with this code:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(category) %>% 
  mutate(item = fct_reorder(item, n),
         item_fct = as.numeric(item)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(n, item, fill = category)) +
  geom_col()
```

[image: Plot]

If the items are factored from 1-5 in their respective groups and thus share the same overall factor levels, then why does ggplot2 display the bars by the **grouped** variable?
This plot is actually my desired outcome, but I don't understand the logic behind it. Considering the factor levels, I would expect bars of the same factor level to be next to each other (basically starting with "Eggplant", then "Orange", then "Carrot", then "Blueberry" etc.).

I would've assumed that the following table would produce the plot, because here the factor levels are ordered in the same way the bars are ordered in the plot:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 4
   item      category      n item_fct
   <chr>     <chr>     <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 Banana    Fruit        57        5
 2 Ananas    Fruit        19        4
 3 Apple     Fruit        14        3
 4 Blueberry Fruit        11        2
 5 Orange    Fruit         8        1
 6 Spinach   Vegetable   318       10
 7 Cabbage   Vegetable    70        9
 8 Broccoli  Vegetable    33        8
 9 Carrot    Vegetable    31        7
10 Eggplant  Vegetable    23        6
```

Comment: I do not get the same output as you for the grouped example using forcats 0.5.0 (and still did after updating to most recent 0.5.1); my `item_fct` is `c(5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6)` which seems to be what you were expected. What version of `forcats` are you using?

Comment: I used version 0.5.0 and now updated to 0.5.1 but nothing changed in my output. I noticed though that whenever I load the ```tidyverse``` library, I get the following warning: ```Warning: package 'forcats' was built under R version 4.0.4```. Might this be an explanation?

Comment: I get the same output as Jon. `c(5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6)` and I am on `‘0.5.0’`. Try restarting R and then try again.

Comment: Unfortunately, restarting R doesn't do the trick as well... ```Item_fct``` is still labeled 1-5. I updated ```forcats``` and reinstalled ```tidyverse```.

Comment: After reinstalling each package from the tidyverse individually, it finally works. ```item_fct``` is now labeled from 1:10. Thanks for the help!
Out of curiosity though, why was ```item_fct``` labeled 1-5 in the first place? What does the package version have to do with this?

Comment: After looking a bit, I suspect the change was in dplyr, which has had updates in recent years to make it handle factors within grouped mutates more predictably, e.g. here with a 1.0.0 update in may 2020: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/news/index.html#vctrs-1